# Getting Segmentation Fault in nvidia-340-updates

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glsl, nvidia

I was kinda doing learning SDL OpenGL for C++(my mistake),and I had to port it to C.Because C++ is kinda confusing for me (btw. Yes I can search the web for an function alternative). So running this gave me an error in which seems to be in the NVIDIA driver (btw. the card is GeForce 105m).Is this my fault or bug in the driver (I think its me because every game on it seems to work fine)?

Here's the gdb backtrack:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00007ffff59cf699 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340-updates/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#2  0x00007ffff59d1d89 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/nvidia-340-updates/libnvidia-glcore.so.340.76
#3  0x0000000000401f86 in compileShader ()
#4  0x0000000000401ca6 in compileShaders ()
#5  0x00000000004018b9 in initShaders ()
#6  0x0000000000401a02 in Initilize ()
#7  0x00000000004015ae in main ()
```

And here's the compileShader func (I won't do the whole code because it's too long ;), I can still post it if you want to):

```
void compileShader(char* filePath, GLuint id) {

    //Open the file
    FILE *shaderFile = fopen(filePath, "rw");
    if (shaderFile == NULL) {
    char *str;
    sprintf(str,"Failed to open %s", &filePath);
        fatalError(str);
    }
    //File contents stores all the text in the file
    char * fileContents = "";
    char symbol;
    //Get all the lines in the file and add it to the contents
    while ((symbol = fgetc(shaderFile)) != EOF ) {
        fileContents += symbol;
    }
    fileContents += EOF;
    fclose(shaderFile);
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &fileContents, NULL);
    glCompileShader(id);
    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glDeleteShader(id);
    char *str;
    sprintf(str,"Shader %s failed to compile", filePath);
        fatalError(str); //Don't worry this just prints out the error
    }
}
```

Comment: `fileContents += symbol;` - `fileContents` is a `char*`; not a `std::string`; this isn't C++; that isn't going to "add" file content to *anything*. You're moving a pointer address to an invalid value; not appending data. None fo the read-data was stored *anywhere*. Subsequent use of said-pointer is naturally invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it isn't C. So I replaced it.

Comment: I understand that. What I meant in my last comment is simply `char* in C` will not behave as `std::string` or other similar containers do in C++. They're fundamentally different in nearly every way. That part of your port is simply broken. there are numerous examples on SO and the web in-general on how to load a dynamic-sized buffer with file content using C constructs. I would urge you seek them out. Better still, learn C++ and use the original library as it was meant to be used.

Comment: Here's a Gist with a set of C functions for loading shaders from files: https://gist.github.com/datenwolf/f108f2ed4085f3840457

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in your code.

The `fileContents` pointer your are giving to the driver is totally invalid, hence the driver crashes when dereferencing this pointer.

You don't have a native string data type in C, you just work with arrays of `char`. And C won't do any kind of memory management for you. As a result, the +=   operator on char pointers does not do string concatenation. This is just pointer arithmetic. You just have an emoty string in memory and `fileContent` pointing at it initially. By the line

```
fileContents += symbol;
```

you increase that pointer by the numerical value of `symbol`, hence pointing to some memory beyond that empty string.

I don't wan't to sound rough, so please don't get me wrong. But I really recommend that you learn the programming language you want to use first, before going on with OpenGL.